# List of object access in Professional Edition

Tags: standard-objects, professional-edition, permission-sets

I have Professional Edition.
I have installed one App and I have one VF page which has one picklist with a list of 
**Contact, Account, Opportunity and Lead** out of these I am able to access only **Contact** none of the rest.
This works fine in developer org.

So can I have list of Objects accessibility in Professional Edition ? or There is there some other issue ?

Comment: What do you mean by, can't access? Error message? No information displayed? A blank page that has nothing, just white? Internal server error? Details!

Comment: No error messages, it just that my Batch classes took so long to run and in some of the PE, I am not able to see some object in a picklist which i have added them using Dynamic "Schema.XYZ_____" methods and logic.

Answer (score 1):

You should have access to Contacts, Accounts, Opportunities and Leads in PE.

You can [watch a video on the key features](https://webevents.force.com/s/pe-tour.html) (which cover most of these) here,

and the "feature" [breakdown comparison can be read here](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=limits_general.htm&language=en_US) - I can't actually seem to get my hands on a specific list of object access!!

I would suspect the problem you are seeing is connected to security or app settings instead?